# How to store an NSDictionary to disk and read back in?

Tags: iphone

I'm getting an NSDictionary from the user defaults database which has key-value pairs of user settings. So the same content as NSUserDefaults dictionary has.

```
NSLog(@"%@ defaults = %@", [self class], 
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
   persistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]]);
```

What would be the easiest way to persist that guy to disk and read back in as NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDictionary has the [writeToFile:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHDBHDB) method to store it and the [dictionaryWithContentsOfFile](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:) method to read it back in.

EDIT : THe article linked to in The MYYN's answer has a few good examples of this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Article on **Serialization in Cocoa - Property Lists**:

- http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/167

> Property Lists are very useful for passing information between processes, storing configuration parameters, and much more. It’s a very powerful concept that nicely expands Mac and iPhone OS serialization and configuration capabilities.